# Strange behavior of QLineEdit widgets in QDialog, binding button function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new with programming in pyqt, so maybe i am wrong with this, but i have found that  self.lineEdit on Enter pressed calls for button's function, even when self.handleKeyRelease is commented. This is minimum of code and first place where i have found that strange behavior.

```
self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)

# self.lineEdit.keyReleaseEvent = self.handleKeyRelease

self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda event: self._insertIntoCategories(db, self.lineEdit))
```

second place of this same behaviour are ,dynamically made, form-like widgets (there is one LineEdit and 3 buttons in a row)

```
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(item[1])    


        # ------------------------------------  block ------------------------------------------------- #

        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)       

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda event, id=item[0], le=self.lineEdit_2: self.modal('edit', 'Are you sure you want to rename this category ?', id, le))

        # ------------------------------------  block ------------------------------------------------- #

        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda event, id=item[0]: self.__chIcon(id))


        # ------------------------------------  block ------------------------------------------------- #

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda event, id=item[0], le=self.lineEdit_2: self.modal('delete', 'Are you sure you want to delete this category ?', id, le))
```

each of this buttons works fine, but each entry on Enter press(or release) again calls for function from previous part of the code (self.pushButton's function) self._insertIntoCategories If this code is not sufficient, there is full code on github if needed.

fully executable code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self):
        self.Form = QtGui.QDialog()
        Form = self.Form
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(504, 550)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0  green, stop:1 white);"))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))

        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))

        # -------------- start of widget definitions -------------------------- #

        # THIS IS FIRTS INPUT #

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        # AND THIS IS FIRST BUTTON

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(imgs/required/btns/add.png);background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 white, stop:1 white);"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda event: self.btnBehavior())
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        # -------------- end of widget definitions -------------------------- #


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.frame_2 = QtGui.QFrame(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 green, stop:1 white);"))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_2"))

        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))

        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_3"))

        self.frame_3 = QtGui.QFrame(self.frame_2)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 white, stop:1 green);"))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_3"))

        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))


        # -------------- start of widget definitions, second row -------------------------- #

        # THIS IS SECOND INPUT

        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame_3)

        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)


        #THIS IS SECOND, THIRD AND FOURTH BUTTONS

        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(imgs/required/btns/edit.jpg);background-color: transparent;"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda event: self.btnBehavior())
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(imgs/required/btns/ch_pic.png); background-color: transparent;"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda event: self.btnBehavior())
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(imgs/required/btns/trash.png);background-color: transparent;"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda event: self.btnBehavior())
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        # -------------- end of widget definitions -------------------------- #

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)

        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>rename</p></body></html>", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>picture</p></body></html>", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>delete</p></body></html>", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setWhatsThis(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>delete</p></body></html>", None))

    def btnBehavior(self):
        print('btn clicked');


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Form = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi()
    ui.Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: An executable code would be useful :)

Comment: here's the git  https://github.com/Dusan92Atanackovic/luqi/tree/pyqt

file to be called is luqi.py, and then press ctrl+shift+c to get new pop-up form

Comment: in the code that is class addCategoryForm widget instances are in first two functions

Comment: Do you think you could create a minimal working example?

Comment: Linking to code on Github is bad practice because future readers may find that the code has changed. So I agree with Matho. Please spend some time to make a small, self-containing example that we can just copy-paste-execute. You will get a lot more help that way. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to make one.

Comment: ok, i have modified cat_form.py  (git branch pyqt) in order to represent my problem, you can download that file and run it, and with pressing enter inside of any inputs (2 provided with this example) you should see that they are calling function "btnBehavior". It's maybe not minimal code but code is reduced to that smaller part, and i have marked, in the code, widget declarations ,so you can easily find them. If you need any more reducing i will try.

Comment: i can put whole code here, but it has 180+ lines

Comment: i have added fully executable code in my question above

Comment: "i can put whole code here, but it has 180+ lines" It's probably not a minimal example then. If you remove all code that is not necessary for the problem, do you still end up with 180+ lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop):

> **autoDefault : bool**
>
> This property holds whether the push button is an auto default button
>
> If this property is set to true then the push button is an auto
>   default button.
>
> In some GUI styles a default button is drawn with an extra frame
>   around it, up to 3 pixels or more. Qt automatically keeps this space
>   free around auto-default buttons, i.e., auto-default buttons may have
>   a slightly larger size hint.
>
> This property's default is true for buttons that have a QDialog
>   parent; otherwise it defaults to false.
>
> See the default property for details of how default and auto-default
>   interact.

That is, this is the responsible property of this problem. The workaround is to set the `autoDefault` property to `False` for **all QPushButtons**.

To do it in a simple way I have restructured your code, to do this put the state of Qt Designer has generated and then implemented the logic that implements that design, given this is my proposed solution:

```
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        for pb in self.findChildren(QtGui.QPushButton):
            pb.setAutoDefault(False)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnBehavior)

    def btnBehavior(self):
        print('btn clicked')
```

As @ekhumoro says you can do the same with Qt Designer, .

[image]

Comment: Yes, this may be more elegant way, but QWidget also works for me. Reason, why i, personaly, don't like this way even it works, more than QWidget is because i have to overwrite default behavior of wigdet e.g making new class that inherits, other classes, just for making such minor changes

Comment: either way i have accepted your answer, since it works, and maybe someone else will need it

Comment: The main problem is that you have chosen a bad template, Qt Designer will probe you several templates, I recommend using the Widget template. :P

Comment: Each template in Qt Designer has its function, for example the Dialog is recommended to use for forms where there is an accept button, such as records, MainWindow is for complete applications where you need to have a ToolBar, StatusBar, DockWidgets, Menus, etc. QWidget Is used to create custom widgets; Since each of them has certain behaviors due to its functions. :P

Comment: well main problem is that i am new with PyQt, i was using tkinter for all my gui applications before (mostly for practice and fun), but i am not satisfied with it anymore, because some advance styling in tkinter is almost impossible, also scrollbar doesn't work as one would expect

Comment: PyQt is a very wide library, I recommend you read the Qt documentation since it is very good, PyQt is Qt wrapper for python and generally does not have good documentation. Tkinter has interesting things but PyQt has many more, little by little you will learn how to use it and it will look great to you.

Comment: yes, i have noticed that documentation is very bad, that is also problem for beginner with pyqt like me

Comment: @DušanAtanacković. There's no need to reset the auto-default property in code. If you are using Qt Designer, you can uncheck `autoDefault` in the Property Editor for each button.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `QDialog` as the basis for your form, I found this [link](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-June/023406.html) where the poster noticed the same thing you did, you can remedy the behaviour by changing the base class to QWidget, I didn't delve more deeply into it, but my guess is that it has something to do with intended uses for returnPressed() behaviour specific to QDialog. If you don't want to use the QWidget maybe you should try and reimplement  the `returnPressed()` method, more about that on this [link](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/).

Comment: you are right, after changing class  from QDialog to QWidget everything works normaly