# How to correctly attach an eventFilter with installEventFilter to a QtWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgis

I am writing Python code around a C++ application based on Qt5. My Python code is passed an instance / object of the `QMainWindow` class - which is implemented in C++. I can neither derive from this class nor modify it - I am just receiving an existing object.

I receive the object (or a handle on it) while the window is still being initialized. By the time my code sees it, it has not been displayed yet. My code is supposed to run a function once the `QMainWindow` object has actually been displayed.

From what I gather, a Qt widget will [emit `QEvent.Polish` once it has been fully displayed](https://forum.qt.io/topic/6386/how-can-i-check-if-qmainwindow-is-fully-loaded/10), also see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html). `QMainWindow` is derived from `QWidget`. This is what I intend to grab and use as a trigger for my code. Based on [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45368148/1672565), I can achieve this by registering an `eventFilter` on the `QMainWindow` object, see [Qt's documentation on `installEventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

`installEventFilter` expects a `QObject` (or something derived from it). I found a small / minimal example [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-April/022596.html). The following snipped is based on it:

```py
class something:

    def __init__(self, some_mainwindow_obj):
        "some_mainwindow_obj is an instance of QMainWindow written in C++"

        self.some_mainwindow_obj = some_mainwindow_obj
        self.wait_for_mainwindow = True
        delay_on_load(self.my_func, some_mainwindow_obj)

    def my_func(self):
        "MUST ONLY RUN WHEN some_mainwindow_obj HAS BEEN FULLY DISPLAYED"

        if not self.wait_for_mainwindow:
            return
        self.wait_for_mainwindow = False

        # do something useful NOW ...

def delay_on_load(func, qt_widget):

    from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QEvent
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

    QMessageBox.warning(None, 'TEST', 'Installing filter ...')

    def wrapper():
        qt_widget.removeEventFilter(filter_obj)
        func()

    class filter_class(QObject):
        def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
            QMessageBox.warning(None, 'TEST', 'Got event type "%s"' % str(event.type())) # DOES NOT TRIGGER AT ALL
            if event.type() == QEvent.Polish: # and obj is qt_widget:
                wrapper()
                return True
            # return QObject.eventFilter(obj, event)
            return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    filter_obj = filter_class()
    qt_widget.installEventFilter(filter_obj)

    QMessageBox.warning(None, 'TEST', '... install done.')
```

As far as documentation goes and other examples show, this should work. However, **my `eventFilter` routine is not even triggered a single time**. What am I doing wrong?

---

An earlier, [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57526855/1672565) on the same subject - inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14356121/1672565) and one of its [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39731872/1672565).

Comment: Isn't the problem simply that `filter_obj` is destroyed as soon as `delay_on_load` finishes?  Or am I misreading the code?

Comment: @G.M. That's not how Python works to my understanding. I am passing a reference to `filter_obj` to another function, which stores it, which in return keeps it in memory. I may be wrong due to the interaction with C++, but if it was pure Python, it should not be a (the) problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc That's a little tricky since you need a C++ app to reproduce it. Maybe I can come up with an idea ...

Comment: @s-m-e What ***specific*** kind of object is `some_mainwindow_obj`? Is it a *PyQt* wrapper for the C++ class? I tested your code with a normal PyQt QMainWindow, and it all works as expected. The only error is caused by the line `return QObject.eventFilter(obj, event)` which must be replaced with `return super().eventFilter(obj, event)`. It also helps to replace all the message-boxes with `print` in order to get sane output. After adding `print('my_func:', self.wait_for_mainwindow)` to the top of `my_func`, I see `my_func: True` in the output.

Comment: @s-m-e I suggest you try creating a script similar to the one described above as a sanity check. Once you've verified that it works with a normal PyQt class, you can then try it with your C++ class. If you get different output, you'll know where the problem lies...

Comment: @s-m-e If it is c++ it does not interest, just provide it, if I do not understand it, another will understand. Provide the MRE but your question is off-topic since as ekhumoro points out the method works and probably the error is in the part that you do not show

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your help. After toying with the above code and your fix, I am certain that it should actually work and the issue is buried in the C++ app I am working with.

Comment: @eyllanesc It's not any C++ app, its QGIS ;) Its developers provided me with a workaround. Nevertheless, if someone wants to dig into the issue: I am working with the QGIS mainwindow, created from the [QgisApp class](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/751f15410a1c95c03a0f6a84e35b6ce538fc4f0d/src/app/qgisapp.h#L177).

Comment: @ekhumoro Just out of interest: Should not `QObject.eventFilter(obj, event)` and `super().eventFilter(obj, event)` in this case be equivalents?

Comment: @s-m-e Not quite. The equivalent would be `QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)`, since you're invoking an instance-method via the class.

Comment: @ekhumoro I missed this one, yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @s-m-e Since this question is specific to qgis, maybe you should try [gis.se] instead?